# Missing or insufficient permissions. request.auth seems to be null

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I implemented the following security rules:

```
  match /client/{clientId} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
    allow update, delete,create : if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == clientId;
    //allow create: if request.auth != null;
    match /notifications/{notificationId} {
      allow read,delete,update: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == clientId;
        }
    match /pointsHistory/{pointHistoryId} {
        allow read,create: if request.auth != null  && request.auth.uid == clientId;
    }
    match /subscribedTopics/{subscribedTopicId} {
        allow read,create,delete: if request.auth != null  && request.auth.uid == clientId;
    }
    match /userSavedAlerts/{userSavedAlertId} {
      allow read,write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == clientId;
    }
    match /userSavedPosts/{userSavedPostId} {
      allow read,write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == clientId;
    }
  }
```

On my app.js I added this to check if a user is already logged in:

```
    const unlisten = auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user && auth().currentUser) {
        setUserAuthData(user);
 
        var db = firebase.firestore();
        var docClientRef = db.collection("client").doc(auth().currentUser.uid);

        docClientRef
          .get()
          .then((clientDoc) => {
            if (clientDoc.exists) {
              console.log("client doc exists: ", clientDoc.data());
              const userData = clientDoc.data();
            }
             // getting “Missing or insufficient permissions.” Trying to read from clients collections
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("error ", error);
           
          });
      } 
    return () => {
      unlisten();
    };
  }, []);
```

I get the following error message: `Missing or insufficient permissions. request.auth seems to be null`. How can I resolve this error? I checked other stack overflow answers but nothing helped. Auth is seems to be null for firebase. I tested release app on TestFlight and debug on Xcode on iPhone device. Nothing works

Edit: printing the onauthstatechanged:

```
'user onUserChanged', { _auth: 
       { _app: 
          { _name: '[DEFAULT]',
            _deleted: false,
            _deleteApp: [Function: bound deleteApp],
            _options: 
             { databaseURL: '***********',
               projectId: '*******',
               gaTrackingId: null,
               appId: '********************',
               messagingSenderId: '***********',
               apiKey: '*****************',
               storageBucket: '********' },
            _automaticDataCollectionEnabled: true,
            _initialized: true,
            _nativeInitialized: true },
         _nativeModule: 
          { createUserWithEmailAndPassword: [Function],
            linkWithCredential: [Function],
            reauthenticateWithCredential: [Function],
            signInAnonymously: [Function],
            signInWithCredential: [Function],
            signInWithCustomToken: [Function],
            signInWithEmailAndPassword: [Function],
            signInWithEmailLink: [Function],
            updatePhoneNumber: [Function],
            addAuthStateListener: [Function],
            addIdTokenListener: [Function],
            applyActionCode: [Function],
            checkActionCode: [Function],
            confirmPasswordReset: [Function],
            confirmationResultConfirm: [Function],
            delete: [Function],
            fetchSignInMethodsForEmail: [Function],
            getIdToken: [Function],
            getIdTokenResult: [Function],
            reload: [Function],
            removeAuthStateListener: [Function],
            removeIdTokenListener: [Function],
            sendEmailVerification: [Function],
            sendPasswordResetEmail: [Function],
            sendSignInLinkToEmail: [Function],
            setAutoRetrievedSmsCodeForPhoneNumber: [Function],
            setLanguageCode: [Function],
            setTenantId: [Function],
            signInWithPhoneNumber: [Function],
            signOut: [Function],
            unlink: [Function],
            updateEmail: [Function],
            updatePassword: [Function],
            updateProfile: [Function],
            useDeviceLanguage: [Function],
            useEmulator: [Function],
            verifyBeforeUpdateEmail: [Function],
            verifyPasswordResetCode: [Function],
            verifyPhoneNumber: [Function],
            APP_USER: 
             { '[DEFAULT]': 
                { metadata: { lastSignInTime: 1652986981780, creationTime: 1609348971231 },
                  providerData: 
                   [ { email: '*****@gmail.com',
                       phoneNumber: null,
                       photoURL: '*************',
                       displayName: '**** ****',
                       uid: '107327466708257974027',
                       providerId: 'google.com' } ],
                  phoneNumber: null,
                  photoURL: '********',
                  displayName: '*** ***',
                  email: '****@gmail.com',
                  uid: 'W81uqWYK6SOfl6ZC1yKPqgOAU382',
                  tenantId: null,
                  isAnonymous: false,
                  emailVerified: true,
                  providerId: 'firebase' } },
            APP_LANGUAGE: { '[DEFAULT]': null },
            getConstants: [Function] },
         _customUrlOrRegion: undefined,
         _config: 
          { statics: 
             { AppleAuthProvider: [Function: AppleAuthProvider],
               EmailAuthProvider: [Function: EmailAuthProvider],
               PhoneAuthProvider: [Function: PhoneAuthProvider],
               GoogleAuthProvider: [Function: GoogleAuthProvider],
               GithubAuthProvider: [Function: GithubAuthProvider],
               TwitterAuthProvider: [Function: TwitterAuthProvider],
               FacebookAuthProvider: [Function: FacebookAuthProvider],
               OAuthProvider: [Function: OAuthProvider],
               PhoneAuthState: 
                { CODE_SENT: 'sent',
                  AUTO_VERIFY_TIMEOUT: 'timeout',
                  AUTO_VERIFIED: 'verified',
                  ERROR: 'error' } }
```

Comment: Method `onAuthStateChanges()` is an observer, not a tool to login.

Comment: Please edit your question, we even don't know what collection/document you want to read. What `userFunctions.getUserFromFS(user.uid)` that method is doing ?

Comment: @Mises I know onAuthStateChanges() is an observer. Don't worry my app works. I was just showing the way I get the auth user.

Comment: @Mises also edited to show what getUserFromFS is doing